# swig typemap for result of C++ function

Tags: java, c++, swig

I have this structure

```
struct License
{
    time_t creationTime;
        ...
};
```

I want to convert time_t to java.util.Calendar.

```
%typemap(jni) time_t "jobject"
%typemap(jtype) time_t "java.util.Calendar"
%typemap(jstype) time_t "java.util.Calendar"
%typemap(javain) time_t "$javainput"
%typemap(freearg) time_t ""
%typemap(in) time_t {
    if ($input) {
        jclass cls = JCALL1(GetObjectClass, jenv, $input);
        jmethodID f = JCALL3(GetMethodID, jenv, cls, "getTimeInMillis", "()J");
        $1 = JCALL2(CallLongMethod, jenv, $input, f)/1000;
    }
}
%typemap(out) time_t { 
    jclass cls = JCALL1(FindClass, jenv, "Ljava/util/Calendar;");

    jmethodID f = JCALL3(GetStaticMethodID, jenv, cls, "getInstance", "()Ljava/util/Calendar;");
    $result = JCALL2(CallStaticObjectMethod, jenv, cls, f);

    f = JCALL3(GetMethodID, jenv, cls, "setTimeInMillis", "(J)V");
    JCALL3(CallVoidMethod, jenv, $result, f, $1*1000L);
}
```

This is generated License.java

```
public class License {
  public void setCreationTime(java.util.Calendar value) {
    eveusb_javaJNI.License_creationTime_set(swigCPtr, this, value);
  }

  public java.util.Calendar getCreationTime() {
    return new SWIGTYPE_p_time_t(eveusb_javaJNI.License_creationTime_get(swigCPtr, this), true);
  }
```

getCreationTime wrongly uses SWIGTYPE_p_time_t. How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I found the decision. The reason was that time_t was not declared. According to swig documentation, all unspecified types are internally handled as pointers to structures or classes. This declaration fixes my issue

```
typedef long time_t;
```

And now the right code is generated:

```
  public java.util.Calendar getCreationTime() {
    return eveusb_javaJNI.License_creationTime_get(swigCPtr, this);
  }
```